# I'm using editor IntelliJ IDEA 2016 I can't write or edit any code because code keeps highlighting I have installed support of css and bootstrap

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't write or edit any code because code keeps highlighting, I've tried check all settings but unfortunately it seems to not work.

I have installed support of css  and bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Turn of **Vim Emulator** from **Tools** in the IntelliJ, like picture below:

[image]